# Control flow implementation in java

Tags: java, control-flow

I have a list`(List<String>)` as below,

```
        list.add("IF(0.5 > -1)");
        list.add("IF(1!=1)");
        list.add("Print if");
        list.add("ELSEIF(2<=2)");
        list.add("IF(1!=1)");
        list.add("Printing else if");
        list.add("ELSE");
        list.add("Printing else if1");
        list.add("ENDIF");
        list.add("ENDIF");
        list.add("ENDIF");
```

In actual programming above list can be converted like,

```
if(0.5 > -1){
   System.out.println("Print if");
}else if(2<=2){
  if(1!=1){
    System.out.println("Print else if");
  }else{
    System.out.println("Print else if1");
}
}
```

*All the expressions(0.5 > -1 etc,.) and Sys.out are for example and it can be anything.

My problem statement is,

with the above list as an input i have to generate the same behaviuor as actual code does.
Input may also contain **while,nested loops nested if else if-else conditions**.(all possibilities in java).

**(e.g)**

```
list.add("WHILE(i<=5)");
list.add("Execute some thing");
list.add("i++");
list.add("ENDWHILE");
```

where execute something will be called 5 times.

I can understand there should be some sort of **GOTO** logic. Searching in net was of no help.

What logic, algorithm or best way can be used to implement this.

Comment: That's cool. You are trying to create a interpreter.

Comment: I am using Oracle Noshorn and finally be able to achieve what i have asked for by forming a string which contains the code and evaluating it. Still are there any other way or open source interpreters available? to do the task.

Comment: I am not aware of any other interpreters. I will get back to you if i come across one. But your efforts are good.